# What is the most efficient way of submitting a form whose inputs are not direct children of the form element itself using native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, input, submit

I am currently creating a form for my employer which tracks individual employee statistics throughout a typical day, such as number of calls, revenue, items sold, etc. I would like to asynchronously update a database using a simple html form without necessarily having to use the entire jQuery library since all I would be using is the `$.ajax` method, which I do know is effective.

The trouble I'm running into is in finding a way to serialize a form using the form's `<input type="submit">` button. My form's input fields are spatially organized using `<div></div>` tags between the `<form>` element itself and its `<input />` fields themselves, as seen below:

```
<form name="tour_1" id="tour_1">
    <div class="num_calls_cell">
        <input type="text" value="3" name="total_calls" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="acw_cell">
        <input type="text" value="24.35" name="acw" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="rev_cell">
        <input type="text" value="125.34" name="revenue" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="env_cell">
        <input type="text" value="0" name="envelopes" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="pen_cell">
        <input type="text" value="1" name="pens" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="cal_cell">
        <input type="text" value="0" name="other" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="comment_cell">
        <input type="text" value="comment" name="comments" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit_cell">
        <input type="submit" class="submit_tour" value="Submit Tour" />
    </div>
</form>
```

There are a total of four of these forms that I have in one "day" (you may view the actual project [here](http://ryanvold.com/prototype/prototype.php) (http://ryanvold.com/prototype/prototype.php).

How could I most effectively transfer my form data into a PHP file that can easily update a MySQL database using my `<input type="submit">` buttons?

Comment: <input form=tour_1 />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize form  like this:

```
document.getElementById('tour_1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var params = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
        params.push(this.elements[i].name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.elements[i].value));
    }
    params = params.join('&');

    alert(params);

}, false);
```

This will give you params as follows:

```
total_calls=3&acw=24.35&revenue=125.34&envelopes=0&pens=1&other=0&comments=comment&=Submit%20Tour
```

Having constructed `params` string like this you can use it as ajax request POST parameters:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(params);
```

This is just an example, remember to take care of IE if you need to support it (attachEvent).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LnLaT/

Comment: I like it. Will it be detrimental if I have the `&=Submit%20Tour` portion on the params string?

Comment: No, it will be okay. But if you don't want it you can either give button a name or put a check in the loop `if (this.elements[i].name) { ... }`.